# Django sql query sql server

Tags: django, python-2.7, azure-sql-database

I am experiencing a very strange case :

When running this query

```
c.execute ('select * from banks_row_data  where Record_id=544')
test=c.fetchall()
```

The result is None

while when running :

```
c.execute ('select * from banks_row_data')
test=c.fetchall()
```

The result is the entire table

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On the first query you are restricting the results to only record(s) that have Record_Id = 544 but no record(s) with that Id number are stored at this time.

Your second query is not filtering results as the first query does with the WHERE clause, so basically the second query is bringing as result all existent records on that table.

Comment: Thanks, Bu i know for sure (Ran it on the Database) that there is a record with record_id544

Comment: Is the record_id field string or numeric? You are comparing it on the query as numeric data type.